# Property of unitary matrices

Tags: matrices, unitary-matrices

This article - https://doi.org/10.1016/0370-2693(88)91216-6 - states that for a $3 \times 3$ unitary matrix $A$, we have $|A_{33}| = |(A_{11}A_{22}-A_{12} A_{21})|$, where $A_{ij}$ stands for the element in row $i$ and column $j$ of matrix $A$ and |.| stands for the modulus.

Why is this true?

I tried expanding the square of the right-hand side of the equality but I got a term with $\Re(A_{11}A_{22}A_{12}^*A_{21}^*)$ that I don't think can easily be related to $|A_{33}|$ so this may not be the correct procedure.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Already edited it. Is it better now?

Comment: Yes, that's better (+1).

Comment: I'm having trouble with the notation.  Sometimes $|\cdot|$ is used to denote the determinant of a matrix, or (as you perhaps interpreted) as the absolute value of a scalar.  Also some authors use $A_{ij}$ to mean a minor (submatrix omitting row $i$ and column $j$), but it might denote an entry of matrix $A$ (which might for that reason be better denoted $a_{ij}$.

Comment: @hardmath I clarified it. Hope it is good now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the formula $A^{-1} = \frac{\mathrm{adj}(A)}{\det(A)}$, where $\mathrm{adj}(A)$ is the adjugate matrix of $A$. Then, $$\begin{pmatrix}* &* &* \\ * &* &* \\
* &* & \overline{A_{33}}\end{pmatrix} = A^* = A^{-1} = \frac{1}{\det{A}}\begin{pmatrix}* &* &* \\ * &* &* \\ * &* &(A_{11}A_{22}-A_{12}A_{21}) \end{pmatrix},$$ where $*$ represents some matrix entries we don't care about. Comparing the bottom right corners, we get $\overline{A_{33}} = \frac{A_{11}A_{22}-A_{12}A_{21}}{\det(A)}$. Taking the magnitude of both sides gives $|A_{33}| = \frac{|A_{11}A_{22}-A_{12}A_{21}|}{|\det(A)|}$, but $1=\det(AA^*)=|\det(A)|^2$, so this simplifies to the desired result.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is there a similar relation to $|A_{33}| = |(A_{11}A_{22}-A_{12} A_{21})|$ for a non-square matrix $B$ for which we have $B B^\dagger = I$ (where the $\dagger$ stands for conjugate transpose and $I$ stands for the identity matrix)?